# How do I extract Insights data via the API FQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm new to Facebook API and I'm trying to extract the Graph Explorer Insights data, specifically "Likes" and "Talking About This", using the API/FQL table.

I can see these insights data (for our website) through the Graph API explorer.

Can anyone know how I can extract the same data using the API FQL tables?

I've tried using the examples from  the FQL documentation but I'm not getting any data. The query I've tried is :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights  
WHERE object_id=<nnnnnnnnnn> AND metric='page_storytellers_by_age_gender' 
AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-01-15') 
AND period=period('month')
```